# Removing quotes from particular json variables using boost

Tags: c++, regex, json, boost, replace

I am using boost::property_tree to process, edit, then re-output a very large json file (the file comes from a simulator and includes several thousand key-value pairs).  Reading in the json, and making the proper modifications works fine, however the boost property_tree's write_json function outputs all values as strings (as described [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9721)).

In my case, within my json string, there are 10 or so (repeated) keys that will always have a numeric value (the rest of the key names are strings).  So I am wondering if there is a way (likely using boost's regex matching/replacing) to search for a given key, and remove the quotes around its value.  e.g.- if I have the string:

```
... "lots": "of", "key-value": "pairs", "numeric1": "12.3", "numeric2": "45.6", ...
```

I might do a search for "numeric1", then remove the next two quotes after it. Repeat the same for "numeric2" yielding:

```
... "lots": "of", "key-value": "pairs", "numeric1": 12.3, "numeric2": 45.6, ...
```

Note: I might have several hundred "numeric1" keys and several hundred "numeric2" keys that need to be converted to numbers throughout the json string. Thoughts?

Comment: What about just doing a simple replace all using `"(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)"` with `$1` Stringified its `"\"(\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)\""` with `"$1"`

Comment: Why not to use proper json library, for example: header only [rapidjson](https://miloyip.github.io/rapidjson/md_doc_tutorial.html)?

Comment: @sln: That would work nicely as all of my non-number strings are very un-numeric.  Do you know of any example code that does this replacement?  I am not very experienced in the way of boost regex, replacing with a piece of the found string (e.g.- $1) and am having trouble finding examples.

Comment: @doqtor: we are currently in the air between using json and xml (a decision out of my hands) and it looked like property_tree could easily be switched between the two types of output.

Comment: @MarkD - Sure, I'd give you a good example but this is marked as duplicate. If you open a new question that specifically states you need a regex solution for a plain string. (i.e. drop the json tag).

Comment: @sln: no worries.  After a bit of trial an error, and with your hint, I was able to figure it out.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!